# OneM2M NOTIFY blocking rules?

Tags: onem2m

I'm having trouble finding where in the spec it specifies how notification should be queued or blocked in the most trivial case.

Let's assume a simple `mn-ae <=> mn-cse <=> in-cse <=> in-ae` setup. There's a resource `res1` on the `mn-cse`, and the `in-ae` has a trivial subscription on it:

```json
{
    "enc": {
        "net": [3],
        "ty": 4
    },
    "nct": 1,
    "nu": ["<uri>"],
    "pi": "res1",
    "ri": "sub1",
    "rn": "sub1",
    "ty": 23
}
```

There are no other relevant resources or configurations affecting notifications.

Then, let's say the `mn-ae` updates `res1` and that triggers a notification to `in-ae`, and let's say the `in-ae` takes a while to process that notification (*not* long enough to timeout)... While `in-ae` is processing the notification, `mn-ae` does another update to `res1`.

My question is this: *where* (if anywhere) is this second notification blocked?

- in the `mn-cse` ?
- in the `in-cse` ?
- not blocked - `in-ae` receives two concurrent notifications.

Further questions:

- what if it (the 2nd notification) was triggered by a different `in-ae` on the same `mn-cse` ? (ie. are the notification queued based on *target* ?)
- what if the same `in-ae` triggered a different notification on a different resource? (ie. are the notificaitons queued based on *source* ?)
- what if it was a different `in-ae` on a different `mn-cse` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the described scenario for basic subscription on a resource and in response to your first question, notifications are not blocked and in-ae will receive two concurrent notifications. oneM2M does not specify any notification blocking mechanism.

Regarding your further questions (and assuming you meant mn-ae instead of in-ae, guessing in-ae is always the notification target in such scenario), notifications are sent to the target as soon as they are generated, independently of the ae that triggered it or the subscribed-to resource. Notifications from different subscribed-to resources are distinguished by the subscriptionReference attribute in the notification element.

Different setups on the subscriptions or connectivity between the different nodes will make this behaviour vary, i.e. batching notifications, target reachability, etc…